# Internal microphone not detected on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with sound card Intel ALC3204

Tags: sound, alsa, intel, 20.04, microphone

Just updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and my internal mic stopped working. I had this issue before and managed to solve it by installing different kernels until it started working. I tried to do the same thing now, but it didn't manage to find a kernel where the microphone.

My computer is Dell vostro 5940, with sound card intel ALC3204.

After the upgrade the sound card wasn't detected at all, I had to install the intel-microcode package, then it was detected. Now sound works just fine, except for the internal microphone.

`arecord -l` gives the following output:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsklhdacard [sof-skl_hda_card], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsklhdacard [sof-skl_hda_card], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

****** EDIT ******

The output of `wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh` is located here:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=a41c5a028f71c631e749c331669a3e09e5260c42

Another weird thing: when going to pulseaudio I see 2 options in the input devices,

1. Headset Microphon(plugged in)
2. Microphone (unplugged).

There is no external headset microphone plugged in to the computer. When choosing the Microphone (unplugged) option it seems like I'm getting a signal from the internal mic.

---

I saw answers to similar questions here, but nothing helped.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading my kernel to 5.5.18-050518-generic. Have no idea what caused the problem and why.

Comment: I am on 5.11.7 and still have this problem, Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20.04 base), with Dell Inspiron 7706.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my audio and discovered that third-party drivers were responsible to this behave. Check if it didn't mess with your microphone too.

Anyway, this command bellow resolved for me:

```
alsactl restore
```

Comment: Tried it, no luck. How did you discover the third party drivers that were responsible for your problem?

Comment: I discovered changing to the default configuration. Then my audio turned back to normal.